# Converting JList to ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

Is it possible to bring a JList in the format of a ArrayList? I found examples in the way vice versa but not JList -> ArrayList

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `JList` is a graphical component. An `ArrayList` is a generic container. What is it you're doing?

Comment: You probably want to read about Swing *models*. You rather *link* a JList to some underlying list (like some ArrayList) so that updates on the one side get reflected to the other side automatically. Turning a JList into a list ... that very much sounds like the wrong answer to some other problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it try like below:-

In the below example jlist is JList  selectedElements is arrayList

```
 int  inds []= jlist.getSelectedIndices();

 for(int i = 0 ; i < inds.length;i++)
 {
    selectedElements.add((String) (jlist.getModel().getElementAt(inds[i])));
 }
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Converting all elements of a `JList` into an `ArrayList`:

```
List list = new ArrayList(jList.getModel().getSize());
for (int i = 0; i < jList.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
    list.add(jList.getModel().getElementAt(i));
}
```

Comment: Don't use raw types!

Comment: @JacobG. Since we have no idea what type OP wants to convert, the most precise solution you can do is `List<Object>` which effectively is the same in my opinion